# Javascript fetch does not get caught on try/catch block on Node 18

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, fetch, try-catch

Consider the following Javascript function running on NodeJs version 18.10.0 that is called from a timer every minute:

```
get = async (params, token) => {
    let query = new URLSearchParams(params);

    let url =
      "http://localhost:2200:/v1.0/test" +
      (query ? "?" + query : "");

    try {
      let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: new Headers({
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }),
      });

      let data = null;
      let sts = false;

      if (response.status !== 200) {
        if (response.status === 401) {
            console.log("Unauthenticated")
        }
      } else {
        data = await response.json();
        sts = true;
      }

      return { status: sts, data: data };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error on fetch! Cannot get caught here!!!!");
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Works fine and get data from my server on a minute basis.

My problem arises when I stop the server side... I'm getting the error below in the next cycle of fetch. All fine - the server has disconnected - but that is crashing my code, not being caught by the try/catch block:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.processResponse (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6406:34)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6727:42
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:4040
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
    errno: -61,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 4040
  }
}
```

Why is the error bypassing the try/catch block of my code? How to fix it?

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/n36wgbvr/).

Comment: Shows the error in the catch? Here node crashes....